# tar command is not compressing archive file in linux

Tags: linux, zip, tar

I am trying to simply compress a directory using

```
nohup tar cvzf /home/ali/42.tar.gz /home/hadoop/  &
```

It creates the archive but it is the same exact size as the original directory.

I check the file size of the original directory (Includes millions of text files) and it's exactly the same as the one that is supposed to be compressed, it's like the switch to compress is not working.

also, I using **gunzip** command to tell me more details about the compression achieved.

```
[hadoop@node3 ali]$  gunzip -lv 42.tar.gz
method  crc     date  time           compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 7716afb7 Feb 28 10:25       7437323730944          1927010989 -385851.3% 42.tar
```

## update

total capacity of server = 14T
[image]

size of `/home/hadoop` directory = 7.2T

[image]

size of `/home/ali/42.tar.gz` = 6.8T
[image]

Note: In the middle of the compression process, the capacity of the server is filled, therefore the file size is 6.8T.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the output from running gunzip -lv /home/ali/42.tar.gz please? That will tell us more datail about the compression achieved.

Comment: @pmqs  . thanks.  I append the output of the gunzip command.

Comment: That output is suggesting that gzip has increased the size of the file from about 1.8Gig to 6.9Gig. What is the true compressed and uncompressed file sizes. If you don't know the uncompressed size, run this gunzip -c /home/ali/42.tar.gz | wc -c

Comment: You have run out of disk space. The capacity of the disk may be 14T, but you only have 24k free.

Comment: Yes, the server now has 24K spaces.  But before the compression process began, the server had  6.8T  free space.  My question is why the files are not compressed and the size of 42.tar.gz is 6.8T. I tested this command on another server and the compress file size was 3T.

Comment: Not sure what is going on. Once disk space runs out bad things happen.